# TinyMCE and entity encoding - an additional semicolon

Tags: encoding, tinymce, entity

I'm having problems with my CMS - which uses tinyMCE - from appending a semi colon to entities such as & and ®.  Each time I save the document (using tinyMCE), an additional semi colon is added.

My page is using UFT-8 character set, I using the latest jquery-version of tinyMCE, and I've tried - but possibly have gotten confused in the process - altering the entity_encoding option within tinyMCE's configuration from "raw" to "named" to "numeric" and back again - without any apparent solution.

Any insight into a pathway to a solution would be appreciated.

Thanks/Bruce